# return a word from a given array in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I am beginner in kotlin (in coding in general) and am trying to get the following sentence: "The 6 sided [randomColor] dice rolled [randomNumber]". Basically the only part I cannot get correctly is the color, I get "kotlin.Unit" instead. The code I am using is below. Many thanks in advance for your help!

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val myFirstDice = Dice(6)
    println ("The ${myFirstDice.numSides} sided ${randomColor()} dice rolled ${myFirstDice.roll()}")
}
```

```kotlin
class Dice(val numSides: Int){ 
    fun roll(): Int{
        return (1..numSides).random()
    }
}
```

```kotlin
fun randomColor() {
    val list = listOf("black", "yellow", "green")
    val randomColor = list.shuffled().find { true }
}
```

Comment: `randomColor()` does not `return` a value. Also, `first()` would be simpler than `find{ true}`. (Or, for safety, `firstOrNull()` if you couldn't be totally certain that the list's not empty.) And for a fixed list, it's more efficient to create it once (outside the function) than create a new list each time the function is called.

Comment: You can call ``random()`` on a list too - it's a utility function that's defined on a lot of "collection of things"-style objects

Comment: `Dice` is plural, seems more appropriate to use the singular, `Die`.

Comment: @gidds Thanks, that makes a lot of sense! Would you then create the list under fun main ()?  How woud the fun randomColor() look like? Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it a little bit differently. I would not use `shuffled()` method, but instead rely on the built-in `random()` method available since kotlin 1.3 ([reference documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/random.html)):

```kotlin
fun randomColor(): String {
    val list = listOf("black", "yellow", "green")
    return list.random()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the value of `randomColor`:

```kotlin
fun randomColor(): String? {
    val list = listOf("black", "yellow", "green")
    val randomColor = list.shuffled().find { true }
    return randomColor;
}
```

Comment: Might be worth mentioning how weird `find { true }` is.